# Error installing Firebase manually (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I am trying to add the necessary libraries for `Firebase` as indicated on the firebase page in the integration section without cocoapods for a swift project, and the steps that come in the read.me file inside the zip with all the libraries.

Once all the steps are done, **I build the project after a clean and I get the following error:**

> Ld
>   /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Medusa-fdyksfqolvwsiubuevxzsxcgcays/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Medusa.app/Medusa
>   normal arm64 (in target 'Medusa' from project 'Medusa')
>       cd /Users/mac/Documents/Proyectos/Medusa/ios/desarrollo/branches/v1/Medusa
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -target arm64-apple-ios10.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS13.2.sdk
>   -L/Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Medusa-fdyksfqolvwsiubuevxzsxcgcays/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -F/Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Medusa-fdyksfqolvwsiubuevxzsxcgcays/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -F/Users/mac/Documents/Proyectos/Medusa/ios/desarrollo/branches/v1/Medusa/Firebase
>   -filelist /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Medusa-fdyksfqolvwsiubuevxzsxcgcays/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Medusa.build/Debug-iphoneos/Medusa.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Medusa.LinkFileList
>   -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto
>   -Xlinker /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Medusa-fdyksfqolvwsiubuevxzsxcgcays/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Medusa.build/Debug-iphoneos/Medusa.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Medusa_lto.o
>   -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fembed-bitcode-marker -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos
>   -L/usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Medusa-fdyksfqolvwsiubuevxzsxcgcays/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Medusa.build/Debug-iphoneos/Medusa.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Medusa.swiftmodule
>   -ObjC -framework GoogleUtilities /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Medusa-fdyksfqolvwsiubuevxzsxcgcays/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SQLite.framework/SQLite
>   -framework GoogleAppMeasurement -framework CoreGraphics -framework UserNotifications -framework FirebaseMessaging -framework
>   MobileCoreServices -framework FirebaseCore -framework Security
>   -framework Foundation -framework SystemConfiguration -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework nanopb -framework
>   GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport -framework UIKit -framework
>   FirebaseCoreDiagnostics -framework FIRAnalyticsConnector -framework
>   GoogleDataTransport -framework EventKit -framework AssetsLibrary
>   -framework FirebaseInstanceID -framework Protobuf -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Medusa-fdyksfqolvwsiubuevxzsxcgcays/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Medusa.build/Debug-iphoneos/Medusa.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Medusa_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Medusa-fdyksfqolvwsiubuevxzsxcgcays/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Medusa.app/Medusa
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKProductsRequest", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMProductsRequest_9ec051498f83cad93a58cf3f308ab9b6.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKPaymentQueue", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMAnalytics_cb405cb8c995318bf496bd8f1041864f.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I've been looking for this error and it's related to the library **StoreKit.framework** but my application does not need in-app purchases.

Then I put some screenshots of how libraries are added

**General Configuration**

[image]

**Build Phase Configuration**

[image]
[image]

**project structure**

[image: project structure]
[image]

**Any suggestions??**

Comment: May I ask why you are trying to not use Cocoapods? Not only is it much, much easier, but it's also cleaner. Whenever Firebase will update their SDK all you have to do is run a `pod install` and you'll get the updated code.

Comment: Did you make sure the "In-App Purchase" option in the Capabilities section for your app is showing OFF?

Comment: Hi @Pierce, thanks for your comments, I have never used coocoapods and I am quite new to iOS development, and I tried this way. On the other hand, the "In-App Purchase"  option is not activated in capabilities, but if I add the StoreKit.framework, that option is automatically added to me, and I don't want that option

Comment: I am with @Pierce on this. Cocoapods is the way to go unless you have a specific use case preventing it. Even better, [cocoapods.app](https://cocoapods.org/app) makes setting up and installing pods a snap.

Answer (score 1):

StoreKit is a [dependency of AppMeasurement](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/e/3/b/GoogleAppMeasurement/5.3.0/GoogleAppMeasurement.podspec.json#L12) and should be brought in from the modulemap in the GoogleAppMeasurement.framework that you're installing.

You can work around the issue by explicitly adding StoreKit in the `Link Binary with Libraries` Build Phase in Xcode.

Comment: Hi @Paul Beusterien , thanks for your answer, I have tried what you recommend and I get other errors related to the provisioning profile, like this:
'Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *" doesn't support the In-App Purchase capability.', I don't want that my apps support purchases

Comment: Based on https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/2435, the only current option would be to stop using FirebaseAnalytics and stop linking FirebaseAnalytics and GoogleAppMeasurement.